# Convert an IEnumerable<Ienumerable<T>> to Dictionary<key,IEnumerable<T>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am currently seeking a way in which i can convert an
`IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval>` to an `Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval>>`

I tried using the `IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval>.ToDictionary(x => x.id)`
but this just returns an `Dictionary<Guid, DateTimeInterval>` and not the wanted `Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval>>`

What am I doing wrong?

A dateTimeInterval is defined as such:

```
public class DatetimeInterval
{

    public Guid key {get; set;}
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }

    public DatetimeInterval(DateTime from, DateTime to, Guid key)
    {
        Key = key;
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }
}
```

and in the `IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval>` there might exist DateTimeIntervals which have the same keys.

Hence I would very much like have
IEnumerable.ToDictionary(x => x.key, v => v)
To return
but this just returns an `Dictionary<Guid, DateTimeInterval>` and not the wanted `Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval>>`

Comment: `stuff.ToDictionary(k => new Guid(...), v => v)` ?

Comment: @aybe DatetimeInterval has an id itself, 
some of them are the same, hence should be stored in the list

Comment: Add more code to your question because it isn't clear.

Comment: @aybe added some more code.... not sure what is unsure here..

Comment: Are you looking for `ToLookup` instead of `ToDictionary`? Dictionaries are 1:1 key:value while it sounds you are look for 1:many key:value since `DateTimeInterval` can have duplicate ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this use case, one would usually use a [Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=net-5.0) instead of a Dictionary:

```
var myLookup = myEnumerable.ToLookup(interval => interval.Id);
```

This will create an `ILookup<Guid, DateTimeInterval>`. A Lookup is similar to a Dictionary, but it maps keys to a *collection* of values instead of a single value.

---

If you need a dictionary for technical reasons, you can convert your Lookup to a "classic" dictionary:

```
var myDictionary = myLookup.ToDictionary(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: if this creates an `Lookup<Guid, DateTimeInterval>` , how are I then able to retrieve an List of DateTimeInterval with a specific entity_id??

Comment: @IamnotFat: Using `myLookup[myEntityId]`, which will [return an `IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.ilookup-2.item?view=net-5.0). In general, the indexer of an `ILookup<K, V>`  will return an `IEnumerable<V>` (as opposed to a dictionary, which will just return a `V`).

Answer (score 0):

```cs
Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<DatetimeInterval>> target = source
    .ToLookup(di => di.key, di => di)
    .ToDictionary(@group => @group.Key, @group => @group.Select(item => item));
```

- `ToLookup` groups items based on a specified property
- `ToDictionary` converts the `ILookup` implementation to `Dictionary`
- `Select` helps to convert the `IGrouping` to `IEnumerable`

Answer (score -1):

```
var result = source
  .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
  .ToDictionary(
    g => g.Key,
    g => (IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval>)g);
```